# Como sobrescrever uma classe de um projeto externo para chamar uma função

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma solução onde contém 2 projetos.

Um deles é o projeto que puxei pelo github, então não quero modifica-lo pois toda vez que atualizar irei perder minhas configurações.

Nesse projeto tem uma classe chamada:

```
public class Cielo
{
        String sendHttpRequest (String message)
        {
//Quero q toda vez que o sistema chamar esse metódio chame um código meu, ex:
//var gravaXML = new SalvaXML();
//gravaXML.GravarFisicamente(message);
        }
}
```

Porém quero injetar essa função através do meu 2º projeto, Não quero modificar o projeto já pronto vindo do git.
Existe como?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você quer criar a MyCielo que herda da classe Cielo original.

Nessa sua classe você pode alterar qualquer comportamento das funções virtuais e adicionar novos métodos sem problemas.

O que você não vai poder fazer é mexer nas variáveis e métodos privados. Se você conseguir fazer tudo o que precisa no sendHttpRequest usando a parte protegida e pública da classe está até fácil. :)

---

Passo a passo:

**1) Adicione a biblioteca como referência.**

No visual studio, por exemplo, você deve adicionar a lib gerada pelo projeto 1 na pasta correta do VS. (Pode ser "C:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include" para o VS2015).

Ali você cria uma pasta para o projeto com todo o código. E incluir ele como referência no References, clicando com o botão direito e passando a biblioteca.

**2) Crie a classe nova.**

No topo você adiciona o arquivo que aponta para a classe que você quer estender.

```
using Cielo;
```

E nesse arquivo você cria a classe com todas as funções que você precisa.

```
public class MyCielo : Cielo
{
        String sendHttpRequest (String message)
        {
//Quero q toda vez que o sistema chamar esse metódio chame um código meu, ex:
//var gravaXML = new SalvaXML();
//gravaXML.GravarFisicamente(message);
        }
}
```

Comment: poderia colocar um exemplo bem genérico?

Comment: esse #include <projetoExterno/CAMINHOPROARQUIVO/Arquivo.H> é C# ?

Comment: mas só uma questão,o outro objeto não deve chamar mais a classe Cielo base e sim a minha Classe MyCielo que herda todas os métodos da Cielo e ainda adiciona um nova função?

Comment: Isso mesmo... você passa a usar MyCielo no lugar da Cielo.